# Reduce AC frequency

Tags: ac, transformer, frequency

Can a resistor in parallel to L1 of a step down transformer be used to reduce the AC frequency? \$F=\frac{X_L}{2\pi L}\$

Comment: Transformers can't change the frequency of the signal passing through them, neither can inductors. Adding a resistor doesn't change that.

Comment: If the resistor was 0 ohms then the frequency would become zero Hz. There might be a bit of smoke though.

Comment: You are misinterpreting the formula. You are calculating the frequency at which an inductance, \$L\$, has reactance \$X_L\$

Answer (score 1):

Changing the frequency of a signal requires nonlinear circuitry even from a circuit-theoretical POV. Thus no kind of linear element, or a combination of linear elements (a.k.a. a linear circuit), can do what you want.

If you need a signal of lower frequency, but the same power level of your AC source, your best bet is probably first to convert it to a DC voltage and then converting that DC to AC (with desired frequency) using a power inverter.

If you just need a low power signal with a frequency lower than mains AC, build a simple signal generator. At low frequencies you don't need to buy fancy instrumentation to get good results using DIY circuits.

Answer (score 0):

A more mechanical approach would be to use a genset where a motor runs on the source frequency and the generator creates power at your desired output frequency.

Comment: Cheaper option is to use ac/dc-dc-ac inverter.

Comment: ac/dc/-dc/ac inverter sounds good. Where do you buy them? Basically I need to go from RF to mains frequency.